# rbind data.frames in a list in R

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe, rbind

Suppose we have 3 `list`s of `data.frame`s. In BASE R, I was wondering how I could automatically (ex. in a looping structure) `rbind` the `data.frame`s within these 3 lists?

Please note I want the looping structure so it can `rbind` any more number of similar lists (ex. `g4 g5` ...)

```
g1 <- list(b1 = list(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 3:5)))
g2 <- list(b1 = list(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 3:5)))
g3 <- list(b1 = list(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 3:5)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option with `base R`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^g\\d+$")), function(x) x$b1[[1]]))
```

---

Or with `map`

```
library(tidyverse)
mget(ls(pattern = "^g\\d+$"))  %>% 
      map_dfr(~ pluck(., "b1") %>% 
                 extract2(1))
```

Comment: It depends on what the name of the identifier is - if you have named it as `h1, h2, h3 , ..`, then it would be `ls(pattern = "^h\\d+$")`.  Here, `^` specifies the start of the string and `$` the end of the string, matching 'h' followed by one or more numbers (`\\d+`)

Comment: @rnorouzian If you have `xyz`, 'z15', 'g2z` etc, you may need to create a key of string identifiers by yourself.  Or if these are the only objects loaded into the environment, `ls()` would be enough

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Apologize, I overlooked that you want to solve this in Base R

I am not sure if this is exactly what you want but you could use the function `reduce` from `purrr` for this purpose

```
library(tidyverse)
g1 <- list(b1 = list(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 3:5)))
g2 <- list(b1 = list(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 3:5)))
g3 <- list(b1 = list(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 3:5)))

reduce(list(g1,g2,g3), rbind) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  unnest() %>%
  unnest()

# A tibble: 9 x 2
      a     b
  <int> <int>
1     1     3
2     2     4
3     3     5
4     1     3
5     2     4
6     3     5
7     1     3
8     2     4
9     3     5
```

Comment: OP might look for `lst <- mget(paste0("g", 1:3)); out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, function(x) x[[1]][[1]])); out`