# How to rbind data.frames across third level of named lists?

Tags: r, data.table, bind, nested-lists

List "l_start" at level 1 is a named list, itself nesting named lists ("l1", "l1a") at level 2, 
in turn containing 2-3 data.frames (a, b and possibly c) at level 3.

Goal is to rbind the data frames at level 3 based on names if available to get "l_finish"
(A data.table & rlist solution be preferred, but purrr or base would be fine also)

```
# Level 2
l1 <- 
  # Level 3
  list(a = data.frame(matrix(1:4, ncol=2)),
       b = data.frame(matrix(1:4, ncol=2)),
       c= data.frame(matrix(1:4, ncol=2)))

# Level 2
l1a <- 
  # Level 3
  list(a = data.frame(matrix(1:6, ncol=2)),
       b = data.frame(matrix(1:6, ncol=2)))


# Level 1 "l_start"
l_start <- 
  list(l1, l1a)
names(l_start) <- c("l1", "l1a")
```

How "l_finish" should look

```
l_finish <- 
  list(l1_1a = list(a = rbind(l1$a, l1a$a),
                 b = rbind(l1$b, l1a$b)))
```

Hoped for final product "l_finish"
Note that c is dropped because not in both lists

```
l_finish
#> $l1_1a
#> $l1_1a$a
#>   X1 X2
#> 1  1  3
#> 2  2  4
#> 3  1  4
#> 4  2  5
#> 5  3  6
#> 
#> $l1_1a$b
#>   X1 X2
#> 1  1  3
#> 2  2  4
#> 3  1  4
#> 4  2  5
#> 5  3  6
```

## Close but couldn't quite get there with these

Rbind happening one level above my example
[rbind dataframes across nested lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41596326/rbind-dataframes-across-nested-lists/41596448#41596448)

Only one df name in the list, not multiple
[rbind data.frames in a list in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56211943/rbind-data-frames-in-a-list-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `purrr` solution :

```
library(purrr)
cols <- intersect(names(l_start[[1]]), names(l_start[[2]]))

map(l_start, `[`, cols) %>% transpose() %>% map(bind_rows)

#$a
#  X1 X2
#1  1  3
#2  2  4
#3  1  4
#4  2  5
#5  3  6

#$b
#  X1 X2
#1  1  3
#2  2  4
#3  1  4
#4  2  5
#5  3  6
```

We select the common names in list using `intersect`, `transpose` them and bind the rows.

Comment: Thank you so much, this indeed answers my original question. I made a mistake though, I have multiple lists at level 2, each including varying data.frames. list(l1, l1a, l2, l2a) to transform to list(l1_1a, l2_l2a). Are you able to modify your answer to allow for this multiple level 2 lists? Apologies for not getting it right on the first try.

Comment: @DavidLucey hmmm...I am not sure if I understand. Can you post an example of your actual list structure and show the expected output for the same?

Comment: I found another way to do it, but yours answered the question I asked, so accepted. Many thanks